# Alignment of table rows

Tags: html, css

I want to place the text with the bullets at synchronized position. But when I use text-align: center; the result is not visually good. How I can place the bullets one above another but again at the center of the row?

https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/2/

```
<td>
     <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">list</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&bull; one</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&bull; second</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&bull; thurd</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</td>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/26sP6.png

Comment: It won't be centered anymore if bullets one above another. Either one or another.

Comment: Can you show me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really have both, centered, and bullet points obove another..

Try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wL66hewd/)

you can adjust, by editing the padding-left

```
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:left; 
}

.left-padding{
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: can't think of any...
i don't know a solution, which centers the bulletpoints. you can change the percentage also to pixels if you want a static padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `align-text:left`

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:left; 
    padding:3px 20px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#A4A4A4">top text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
         <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">list</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&bull; one</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&bull; second</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&bull; thurd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="font-family:verdana; color:#424242">main list</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>for test one</td>
                    <td>and test second</td>
                    <td>1 test threee</td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&bull; test test  four</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 2 four</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 4 four</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&bull; tests software </td>
                    <td>&bull; software table</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 7 four</td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&bull; test 8 four</td>
                    <td>&bull; test 3 four</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>  </td>
                    <td>&bull; test and four</td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                

            </table>
    </td>  

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#D8D8D8">bottom text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/12/)

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but when in need you can do something like:

```
<td colspan="2" class="left-padding"><div>&bull; one</div></td>

td div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}
```

Using a padding as answered by others is a fine option also but makes lining out your table more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this strict HTML code, than you can't do that with pure css, you will need some javascript magic:

1. CSS: text-align: left;
2. JS: padding-left: calculated value, based on the cell width and the longest list item in the column. This isn't that simple, because of the hierarchy of the table elements.

Other way is placing 
Every bulleted list should be in one cell, containing ul and li

```css
table, tr, th, td{
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Very long title text
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In that case you will face with another problem: the horizontal lines between the points (background html?). So the javascript is the real answer, if you can code.

Comment: Every bulleted list in one cell i9s a good option for me. Can you show me how this solution can be used with this code https://jsfiddle.net/w7eekbcL/2/ please.